# Magento2: Impossible approve discount code in checkout

Tags: magento2

In basket I can approve discount code and work perfect:
[image]

but in second step in checkout impossible. After accept discount no result:
[image]

@ UPDATE

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Więcej informacji] error-processor.js:28:25
```

[image]

Comment: Please check issue in console due to js error it is not working. Sisable your theme try to checkout with default magento theme

Comment: Prashant, I update my topic log from js console.